# Android Navigation Component : BottomNavigationView's selected tab icon is not updated

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview, android-safe-args

I'm using `BottomNavigationView` with Navigation Component. When showing fragment is not root fragment, the tab icon is not updated (selected).

Example:
When I switch between *Tab Home* with Fragment A (which is root fragment) and *Tab Star* with Fragment B (which is also root fragment) it is working fine.
But when I navigate from *Tab Home* to another fragment, like fragment A2, and tap on *Tab Star* and again return to *Tab Home*, still *Tab Star* is selected in `BottomNavigationView`.

[image: Android Navigation Component Bug]

It was working fine with version `2.4.0-alpha05`, This is happening when I updated it to `2.5.0-alpha01`.

build.gradle (app)

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.5.0-alpha01"
```

build.gradle (root)

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.0-alpha01"
```

Graph:
[image: Android Navigation Graph]

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
            android:name="ui.test.FragmentA"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test"
            android:label="FragmentA" >
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_fragmentA_to_fragmentA2"
                app:destination="@id/fragmentA2" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentA2"
            android:name="ui.test.FragmentA2"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test"
            android:label="FragmentA2" />
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
            android:name="ui.test.FragmentB"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test"
            android:label="FragmentB" />
</navigation>
```

Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:title="" />
</menu>
```

Am I doing something wrong? or this is bug?
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please include your navigation graph

Comment: @ianhanniballake done.

Comment: I had the same problem and you describe the issue very well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So what worked for me was the solution that ianhanniballake hinted at in his answer: using setOnItemSelectedListener.

```
// always show selected Bottom Navigation item as selected (return true)
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
  // In order to get the expected behavior, you have to call default Navigation method manually
  NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)

  return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
}
```

This will always select the item and navigate to the associated destination while maintaining multiple back stacks.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Was really getting annoyed with this issue and did not want to separate out into multiple nav graphs. Its already difficult enough having multiple activities that share some fragments and having to duplicate nav routes in each graph. Separating even more based on bottom tab would have been horrendous.

Comment: Worked for me too, thank you. I hope it will not break something else :)

Comment: Yah save me! Thanks for this quick solution!

Comment: works but adds an default animation, is there any way to get rid of the animation or use your own?

Comment: @ueen: Perhaps this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71585108/389582

Answer (score 8):

Given your navigation graph, there is no way to associate `fragmentA2` with your menu item `fragmentA`, so `fragmentA` is not selected when you return to `fragmentA2`. As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210687967#comment2):

> `NavigationUI` has always used the current destination and what graph it is part of as the source of truth for what tab should be selected.
>
> This can be seen by calling `navigate()` to go to your `SecondFragment` - even though you haven't used the bottom nav button, the selected tab was changed because the current destination has changed to `R.id.frag_second`.
>
> So when you `navigate()` to `R.id.frag_hint` via your button in `HomeFragment`, `NavigationUI` receives a callback that the current destination has changed to `R.id.frag_hint`. It looks at that `NavDestination` and notes that there's no menu item that matches `R.id.frag_hint`. It then looks at the destination's parent graph - your `R.id.sample` `<navigation>` element. There's no menu item that matches that ID either, so `NavigationUI` can't associated that destination with **any** menu item and therefore simply does nothing. That is true on all versions of Navigation.
>
> So what is different when you tap on a bottom navigation item? Well, nothing different from a `NavigationUI` perspective in fact: the exact same code runs and the current destination and what graph it is part of is the source of truth for what tab should be selected. In the Navigation 2.3.5, there was no state saved for each tab, so it only 'worked' because selecting a tab forced the ID of the current destination to match the destination of the menu item you just tapped.
>
> So what you're seeing in your sample app is that there's no link between `R.id.frag_hint` and any menu item, which means `NavigationUI` does nothing. If you want to link `R.id.frag_hint` to your Home tab, then that's exactly what a [nested navigation graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs) can be used for.
>
> I.e., your navigation graph should instead look like:
>
> ```
> <navigation
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:id="@+id/sample"
>     app:startDestination="@id/home">
>    
>     <navigation
>         android:id="@+id/home"
>         app:startDestination="@id/frag_home">
>         <fragment
>             android:id="@+id/frag_home"
>             android:name="eu.rekisoft.android.navbug.HomeFragment"
>             tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
>             <action
>                 android:id="@+id/cause_bug"
>                 app:destination="@id/frag_hint"/>
>         </fragment>
>
>         <fragment
>             android:id="@+id/frag_hint"
>             android:name="eu.rekisoft.android.navbug.HintFragment"
>             android:label="Hint"
>             tools:layout="@layout/fragment_hint"/>
>     </navigation>
>
>     <fragment
>         android:id="@+id/frag_second"
>         android:name="eu.rekisoft.android.navbug.SecondFragment"
>         android:label="Second Fragment"
>         tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second"/>
>
> </navigation>
> ```
>
> And your menu XML should be updated to use `android:id="@id/home"` to match your navigation graph.
>
> Now, when you select the Home bottom nav item, the current destination changes to `R.id.frag_hint` (as your state was restored due to Navigation 2.4's support for multiple back stacks) and `NavigationUI` looks at the ID - `R.id.frag_hint` still doesn't match any menu item, but now the parent graph's ID, `R.id.home` **does** match a menu item - your Home menu item, hence, it becomes selected.
>
> The intention that your navigation graph and its structure drives the UI is a key part of how `NavigationUI` works and is working as intended (there was a bug on earlier versions of Navigation 2.4 that broke this driving principle, but that has since been fixed in beta02). All of `NavigationUI` is built on public APIs specifically so that if you want to use some different logic for which bottom nav item is selected that is independent from your navigation graph structure, you can absolutely do that.
>
> You'll note from the [source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:navigation/navigation-ui/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.kt;l=597) that you can call the public [`onNavDestinationSelected`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/ui/package-summary#(android.view.MenuItem).onNavDestinationSelected(androidx.navigation.NavController)) with your `MenuItem` to get the exact same `navigate()` logic which retaining your own ability to return any value from the `setOnItemSelectedListener` (which is what controls whether the tab becomes selected). Similarly, your own `OnDestinationChangedListener` can choose to look at the [`hierarchy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/NavDestination#(androidx.navigation.NavDestination).hierarchy()) of a destination to choose whether to change the selected bottom nav item or not.

So your graphs should also be using nested graphs for each tab:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/graphA">
    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/graphA"
        app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
            android:name="ui.test.FragmentA"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test"
            android:label="FragmentA" >
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_fragmentA_to_fragmentA2"
                app:destination="@id/fragmentA2" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentA2"
            android:name="ui.test.FragmentA2"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test"
            android:label="FragmentA2" />
    </navigation>
    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/graphB"
        app:startDestination="@id/fragmentB">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
            android:name="ui.test.FragmentB"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test"
            android:label="FragmentB" />
    </navigation>
</navigation>
```

Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/graphA"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/graphB"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:title="" />
</menu>
```

Comment: I haven't tested it but it looks like to solve this problem, but at what cost?  Using the presented structure in a complex project that a fragment is accessible from multiple fragments, forces us to duplicate a lot of code, making the graph very complex and unmaintainable. Also we need to declare/edit a fragment/arguments multiple times every time. That's why I do not prefer using this solution. Also note that it works well  in version `2.4.0-alpha05` of the navigation. Also the mentioned issue already has multiple navigations, which makes the case different from mine.

Comment: According to the issue you mentioned, there IS a way for bottom navigation to find out which tab is selected. As it says "It then looks at the destination's parent graph" and in my graph, if it looks at the parent, it can find the `fragmentA` which matches the navigation menu.

Comment: In your graph, there is no *structural* relationship that implies that `fragmentA2` is at all tied to `fragmentA`, no moreso than `fragmentB` or any other random fragment in your graph - you need that shared parent graph that matches your menu item ID to provide that structure that `NavigationUI` depends on.

Comment: So this means that any globally used fragment is out of the question? Similarly, when the same destination (like a detail view) is used from two different menu items, this won't work as the user expects it either, right? So I would have to duplicate that detail view for both menu items? Shouldn't this better be done by inspecting the runtime stack and not the nav graph?

Comment: works perfectly well. I prefer this solution as the accepted solutions feels like a workaround which could break code in future updates.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the version 2.6.0, if this is your case use 2.5.3, it is works like a charm.